# Get the hosts of many websites and services

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, jsoup

How to write the code to crawl this?

A website provides looking up which company is hosting the particular website or service:

- http://hostadvice.com/tools/whois/#fbcdn.net
- http://hostadvice.com/tools/whois/#paypal.com

For example, put fbcdn.net and it gives Facebook. Put paypal.com and it gives eBay.

I have more than 100000 websites and want to see the corresponding companies. Now I'm looking at **Jsoup**, is it the solution? So that I can do:

```
For(String website : websiteSet){
   url = "http://hostadvice.com/tools/whois/#" + website
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();          
   String company = doc.getHost();       
   Map.put(website, company);        
}
```

Any suggestion? Because I hear that the website being crawled might block my request since it sends too many requests in few minutes?

Comment: First you can't use `GET` as the request must be sent as `POST`. Second I believe the massive automated crawling is against their "terms of service".

Comment: Why not use an [API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api) for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about being blocked, then the *CORRECT* solution is:

1. Read the site's "Terms of Service" page.
2. If the ToS page permits web crawling (or doesn't mention it), follow any rules that are set out in the ToS, and whatever the site's "robots.txt" file says.
3. If the ToS forbids crawling, see if they provide an API (to authorized users) to retrieve the information.
4. If the ToS forbids crawling AND there is no API, then contact the site owners and ask for permission to crawl their site, or to obtain the information you require from them in some other way.
5. If they say "No" ... give up.

---

In this case, it is pretty clear that what you are attempting to do is not permitted.  (From a legal perspective, it would be violation of their copyright, and possibly other laws related to unauthorized access to information.)  It is doubtful that there is an API, or that they would give you permission if you asked.  (If you were willing to PAY ... that might change things.)